# VS code new update doesn't retain opened file (tabs) when switching/opening another file

Tags: ide, visual-studio-code

Early February VS Code update seemed to have messed my entire IDE settings.

**Version: 1.42.0**

When I open a file and switch or drag another file to the main working area the previous one just closes even if I double click on the tab to retain the opened file

The only property which could potentially help is `workbench.editor.enablePreview`

What do I do to revert that so that I can have multiple tabs/files open again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the following property in order to retain opened files

`workbench.editor.showTabs`

Check the checkbox

[image]